# Syntax highlighting not working properly

Tags: texstudio, knitr, syntax-highlighting

I'm using TeXstudio and for a while now, every time I write in math mode using `$...$` or `\[...\]`, it highlights most of the commands as if they were syntax errors although it compiles just fine. For example, it highlights `\alpha`, `_` or `^`. However, it works properly if I use certain environments such as `equation`.

I have noticed that the error appears to be a consecuence of using a `.Rnw` file with `knitr`:

If i write the following code, `\alpha` and `_` appear highlighted, but they do not if i omit `opts_chunk$set(tidy=TRUE)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
    library(knitr)
    opts_chunk$set(tidy=TRUE)
@

$\alpha x_1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! I use TeXStudio myself and don't have that problem, atm. Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The easier it is to copy and test your code, the more likely your question will be answered and can help others in a similar situation.

Comment: The problem might lie within TXS, but it might actually be because of something in your code, that's why I ask for it.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a solution to the problem.

Writing

```
attach(opts_chunk)
set(tidy=TRUE)
```

instead of

```
opts_chunk$set(tidy=TRUE)
```

seems to work for me.